# App Store builds for Xamarin.iOS keep failing on Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, ios-provisioning, apple-developer

I have;

- one Developement-Certificate;

  - used to sign a Debug profile for my device;
- one Distribution Certificate;

  - used to sign an AdHoc-profile for my device;
  - used to create an App Store distribution profile;

Debug and AdHoc builds work as expected. Since I could never get the App Store distribution profile to work, I just built the app on my device with the AdHoc profile but selected Release in the configuration manager. Thus an ipa-file was created at the root of the Release directory which I could upload through the Transporter on Mac and it was accepted by TestFlight.
Things changed with the Visual Studio 17.3.3 release (this was the only changing variable in my environment). The app will be treated as an AdHoc build regardless of configuration (which is probably intentional). But now I am lost completely incapable of building for TestFlight.
I create the App store profiles by selecting
*App Store -> selecting the correct App ID -> selecting distribution cert -> selecting a name*
in Apple Developer.
I tried this repeatedly I end up with the infamous MT1006 error every time, regardless of selecting Release or App Store in the configuration manager.
Microsoft's documentation is not helpful at all in this regard as the steps described in the documentation are not even reproducible:

> Click the + button, select iOS App Development and App Store, and click Continue.

I can't select both of these, it's either iOS App Developement or App Store (I'm choosing the later).

> Select a signing certificate and click Continue. Select devices to include in this profile and click Continue.

I can't even select a device when selecting App Store distribution.

What am I doing wrong? I can see the issue being the fact that I cannot build my App Store release build on a device I never provisioned for, but how else am I supposed to build the archive if I can't even select a target device for the profile?

Comment: As only you have access to data to debug the project, only you are capable to debug it. If you can't then set the new project, and copy code there.

Comment: @IvanIčin I have not problem debugging. This regards only to release builds for iOS.

Comment: Not sure if you have problem with that but you definitely have problem with the meaning of the word debugging.

Comment: @IvanIčin Care to elaborate? I use the term in only one regard, namely in the context of using an iOS development certificate & profile to use for my project's *debug* configuration. I do not understand where you are getting at.

Comment: Debugging is resolving the problem. The debugger is just one of the tools you can use in debugging. If there is the problem in release mode you clearly need to do debugging - finding the cause of the bug/problem and removing it. Decades age there was no debugger, but there was still debugging.

Comment: @IvanIčin I specifically clarified that I am referring to the 'Debug' configuration in visual Studio. Since it's the archive's & profile's configuration and generation and not the source code itself that causes the issue I don't see how this suggestion is applicable here at all and not just nit-picking on terminology irrelevant to my actual question.

Comment: It is fairly trivial to make provisional profiles. Not to say that it requires no time at all to do it first time, but many thousands of people have done it. I suggest you to learn it on the empty project to rule out that you have some problem in your project.

Comment: @IvanIčin I tried this with several blank projects templates (MAUI, Xamarin.ios, Xamarin.Forms) hence the question. Completely disregarding of the fact that "many thousand people have done it" is probably the most abysmally dull argument against the legitimacy of any question - especially on a SW development Q&A site - the alleged triviality raises the question why there are already countless questions on the topic not just here but elsewhere as well. If the solution to the question is so blatantly trivial, you are free to flag it and let the moderators close it, or provide the solution.